# Unable to match style in Text composables

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am unable to match style of the text in `Text` composables, one composable takes `AnnotatedString` the other takes `String` as a parameter.

Sample code along with the output of both composables are shown below. You can see that probably `letterSpacing` is different in both of them that causes different word counts on every line.

```
    val font by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
                FontFamily(
                        Font(R.font.roboto_bold, weight = FontWeight.Bold),
                        Font(R.font.roboto_medium, weight = FontWeight.Medium),
                        Font(R.font.roboto)
                )
        )
    }
    val textStyle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
                TextStyle(
                        fontFamily = font,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
                        fontSize = 14.sp,
                        lineHeight = 20.sp,
                        letterSpacing = 0.25.sp,
                )
        )
    }
    Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            text = AnnotatedString(
                    text = loremIpsum,
                    spanStyle = textStyle.toSpanStyle(),
                    paragraphStyle = textStyle.toParagraphStyle()
            ),
            style = textStyle
    )
    Divider()
    Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            text = loremIpsum,
            style = textStyle
    )
```

[image: comparison]

I attempted to unify the style of two `Text` composables, expecting them to have identical appearances. However, I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `spanStyle = textStyle.toSpanStyle()` in your `AnnotatedString`, it does various check and styling code inside for the whole string and somehow make the letter spacing different.

Based on your example code you don't have any different styling logic that requires a list of SpanStyle to be passed in, so just remove it